# In Symfony 2 getting error like Fatal error: Class ...\Controller\Swift_SmtpTransport' not found?

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

```
I am  new to Symfony Swift mailer. I have tried the following code bellow to configure the username and password
```

But having problem loading such a  class like Swift_SmtpTransport.

```
   $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
                ->setUsername('xxxxxxxx@gmail.com')
                ->setPassword('yyyyyy');

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

    $body="body-text";
    $subject="subject-text";
    $message->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom('xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('zzzzzzzzz@gmail.com')
        ->setContentType('text/html')
        ->setBody($body);
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
    return $result;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you import it with `use` statement?

Comment: If you don't want to ```use``` statement in Controller, you can prefix ```\``` for your class. When you ```Swift_SmtpTransport``` type than autoloader lookup in current namespace when you prefix with ```\``` like  ```\Swift_SmtpTransport``` than it will look in root namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
                ->setUsername('xxxxxxxx@gmail.com')
                ->setPassword('yyyyyy');

    $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
```

Comment: yes i did with use Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle; But still facing the problem.

Comment: and also tried                                                        require_once './vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';

Comment: It is bundle for Symfony2, not SwiftMailer Library for Mailing, so you should use like  ```use \Swift_SmtpTransport,\Swift_Mailer,\Swift_Message;```

Comment: Now its not showing that error message... But the page loading and showing  Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in

Comment: I think you should refer [Symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/index.html), and  "execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" error occurred many times during development, but I am sure it is not occurred for class loading in your case.

Comment: Finally i got solution for that.. 
\Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('ssl://smtp.gmail.com',465);

Comment: By adding 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com' on host name. Now its working